# Is the Dlib library free?

Tags: python

Is the Dlib library free? Because at the company we have plans to use it to recognize documents with Python, and we were thinking of using this lib without a headache.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "free" (in particular, [gratis versus libre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre)) and what exactly do you mean by "headache"?

Comment: My company doesn't want to have a headache in the future with a license. For this I wanted to know if the dlib library is free to be used in an institution

Comment: If it is free to be so used, it will be *because* of the licence, not despite it.  Also, could you maybe amend your question to link to this library?

Comment: All open source licenses are free to be used - given some requirements for redistribution of itself or when used as library or as derivative. Open source does Not mean public domain. Read the license for permissions and obligations when distributing it under the license

Comment: It would improve your question if you could add more details. At minimum you should link to the project page of what Dlib you are talking about. The name is so generic that it's pretty easy for multiple projects to be floating around that have the same or a similar name. Also it would be nice to include details like what you want to do (e.g. use the library internally, use it in a product and sell that product, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLIB license seems to be this: https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/LICENSE.txt (pls correct me if I'm referring to the wrong 'dlib project).
The license appears to be permissive, so most users will likely consider it a 'no headache' license.

I cross-checked the license terms against the '4 essential freedoms' https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html and indeed the Boost Software License 1.0 appears to fulfill all of these.

But there are requirements you need to fulfill if you want to use code under this license. It is not in Public Domain, so you should be sure to understand the requirements and fulfill them when you use the DLIB library in your project.

Comment: Confirmation from the FSF that it is both free and GPL-compatible: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#boost